# Unity3D: how to fix "TerrainData.SetHeights error"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, terrain

I have a problem with my terrain. 
When I want to set the altitude it works, but the terrain is always displayed larger than the 2D array I use for the altitude. In this example, my array and terrain are 200x157. So why do I have this overhang in my display?

```cs
    using MoonSharp.Interpreter;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

[MoonSharpUserData]
public class PrefabCreator : MonoBehaviour
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Classmembers for PrefabCreator
    /// </summary>
    private int terrainDepth;
    private int terrainWidth;
    private int terrainHeight;
    private float terrainScale;
    private float maxHeight;


    public void CreateTerrain(int[][] mapData)
    {
        MapScale(mapData);
        Terrain terrain = Resources.Load<Terrain>("TerrainObject") as Terrain;
        Terrain prefabTerrain = Instantiate(terrain, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        prefabTerrain.terrainData = GenerateTerrain(prefabTerrain.terrainData, mapData);

    }

    private void MapScale(int[][] mapData)
    {
        terrainWidth = 0;
        terrainHeight = 0;
        terrainDepth = 10;

        maxHeight = 0;

        bool firstRun = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < mapData.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            terrainHeight++;
            for (int j = 0; j < mapData[i].Length; j++)
            {
                if(mapData[i][j] > maxHeight)
                {
                    maxHeight = mapData[i][j];
                }

                if (firstRun)
                {
                    terrainWidth++;
                }
            }
            firstRun = false;
        }
        Debug.Log("MAXHEIGHT: " + maxHeight);
    }

    private TerrainData GenerateTerrain(TerrainData terrainData, int[][] mapData)
    {

        if(terrainWidth >= terrainHeight)
        {

            terrainData.heightmapResolution = terrainWidth + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            terrainData.heightmapResolution = terrainHeight + 1;
        }
        terrainData.size = new Vector3(terrainWidth, terrainDepth, terrainHeight);

        Debug.Log("Test" + terrainData.heightmapHeight);
        Debug.Log("Test" + terrainData.heightmapWidth);
        Debug.Log("Test" + terrainData.heightmapScale);
        terrainData.SetHeights(0, 0, GenerateHeights(mapData));

        return terrainData;
    }

    private float[,] GenerateHeights(int[][] mapData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Breite " + terrainWidth);
        Debug.Log("Höhe " + terrainHeight);



        float[,] heights = new float[terrainHeight, terrainWidth];

        //Debug.Log("Test" + mapData[2][4]);
        for (int x = 0; x <= terrainHeight - 1; x++)
        {
            //Debug.Log("X = " + x);
            for (int y = 0; y <= terrainWidth - 1; y++)
            {
                //Debug.Log("Y = " + y);
                float value = 0.0f + mapData[x][y];
                heights[x, y] = (value / maxHeight);
                //heights[x, y] = (float)value ;
                Debug.Log(heights[x, y]);
            }
        }

        return heights;
    }





}
```

See the picture in the appendix. I don't understand why the overhangs exist at the edges?

Many thanks in advance People

[image: Unity show]

Comment: When importing raw heightmaps, they are required to have dimensions that satisfy `2^n + 1`. I'd expect setting heights manually from an array would have the same requirements, but I'm not sure what the behavior would be. Your image looks like it might just expand the terrain to those dimensions (in this case 257x257) and defaulting the values to zero. Have you tried using an `int[257][257]` data source?

Comment: Could you extend the question with all code necessary to reproduce the issue? Including your example input array and where exactly your methods get called

Comment: @derHugo 
The function CreateTerrain() is executed by a Lua function. (Therefore the annotation with Moonsharp)

The function looks like this (with more rows and columns, of course): 
return obj.CreateTerrain({
{ 3, 4, 5, },
{ 5, 3, 3, },
{ 3, 4, 5, },
});

Comment: @PatrickNeumüller unfortunately that is not really reproducible for us then...